# SWT set shell size to span multiple monitors

Tags: java, resize, swt, jface

I'm tasked to open a SWT shell so it spans multiple monitors.

So I'm relying on `shell.setLocation(x, y)` to open the shell in the specified location and `shell.setSize(width, height)` to set the dimension.

If I'm using a width larger than a single monitor (e.g. 3840 for two monitors) somehow the shell is adjusted to fit exactly one monitor (that's 1920).

Happens on Windows and Linux.

Minimal example:

```
public class ShellSample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM);
        final Window win = new ApplicationWindow(shell) {
            @Override
            protected void configureShell(final Shell shell) {
                shell.setLocation(0, 0);
                shell.setSize(3840, 100);
            }
        };
        win.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        shell.dispose();
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your issue.

Comment: @Baz Thanks - coding the MCVE revealded that the problem is not related to SWT at all. Coding an E4 application, so probably there's some black magic going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me.

Actually, I was not resizing a SWT shell, but an JFace window.

So the solution was to override the `constrainShellSize` method...